# Setting view-specific maxAllowedContentLength

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config

Is there a way to have view-specific  attribute, maxAllowedContentLength?

For example: Let's say I have two pages in my mvc application, and I want one page to accept Content-Length up to 1 MB, and I want the other to accept Content-Length up to 10 MB?

Answer (score 1):

If they are in different directories, you can give each directory its own maxAllowedContentLength by adding a web.config file. In the subdirectory you only have to add the values that are different from your base directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement custom ActionFilter

```
public class ContentLengthFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public ContentLengthFilter(int maxContentLength)
    {
        MaxContentLength = maxContentLength;
    }
    public int MaxContentLength { get; private set; }
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentLength > MaxContentLength)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

After that apply this attribute on specific action

```
[HttpPost]
[ContentLengthFilter(10000)]
public ActionResult UploadFile()
{
    var count = Request.Files.Count;
```